# CURL for XAMPP 5.6.8 (Mac Yosemite)

Tags: curl, xampp

I have been trying to get help on the Apache Friends forum for this issue, but no one is responding.

I have found a ton of articles about how to enable CURL on Windows with XAMPP, but nothing for Mac other than one article that said to uncomment the line in the php.ini that says `extension=curl.so`, but that extension doesn't exist in the php.ini file.

Any help to get CURL working for XAMPP on a mac would be appreciated!

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

which php.ini file are you looking at? the one in /applications/XAMPP? or the one in /etc/?

xampp on a mac uses its own php in the /Applications/XAMPP/ directory.